# Jumping a week or month in the jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

[PetersenDidIt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135133/petersendidit) did a great job answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652948/error-creating-a-previous-and-next-date-link-for-jqueryui-datepicker-us).

He showed how to use a link to update the jQueryUI Datepicker's selected date by one day. His solution was:

```
$('a#next').click(function () {
var $picker = $("#datepicker");
var date=new Date($picker.datepicker('getDate'));
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
$picker.datepicker('setDate', date);
return false;
});
```

I am trying to modify it to do the same thing for a week or month. According to the [set date](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-setDate) api I should be able to use "+1m" and "+1w" to skip a month or week. I can't seem to get the code working with anything other than "+1".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the same code you have.
when you want one week do like this:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate()+7);
```

when you want one month you can do:

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireBug script debugging. Might be some JS exception being generated.