# How to create previous and next day link near jquery date picker field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, hyperlink, datepicker

I'm novice in Javascript and jquery programming. I need to create a link with '< previous' and 'next >' near of jquery datepicker field. 
After click in this links the days should to come back or to go forward (ex: Day 2014-01-19, after click in next link 2014-01-20).

I've tested the code from this link [Error creating a '< previous' and 'next >' (date) link for jQueryUI datepicker using setdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652948/error-creating-a-previous-and-next-date-link-for-jqueryui-datepicker-u/), but it doesn't work.

When I click in next or previous or next link, nothing happens.

Follow the code that I've tried:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

// Next Day Link
$('a#next').click(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
    refreshSchedule();
    return false;
});

// Previous Day Link
$('a#previous').click(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '-1');
    refreshSchedule();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<form id="dateForm">
    <a href="" id="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
    <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <a href="" id="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</form>
```

EDIT :

rgbflawed thank you so much, works well your suggestion.

But now I've a new problem per example in date picker the default date is 2014-01-19. 
If I click in next link the date picker is updated to 2014-01-20.
But if I click in next again instead to update the date picker to 2014-01-21, the date picker keep the value 2014-01-20.

How can I fix this to update the date picker according as the user click in previous or next link?

For your suggestion work I updated my form, look:

```
<form id="dateForm" target="bla.php" method="post">
    <a href="#" id="previous">&laquo;</a>
    <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <a href="#" id="next">&raquo;</a>
    <input name="OK" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is refreshScedule()?  Is that something that's part of the datepicker UI?

Comment: I don't know what this refreshScedule() means.

I only get this code from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652948/error-creating-a-previous-and-next-date-link-for-jqueryui-datepicker-u/. 

I've search this function in datepicker UI but I don't find nothing. Is this code responsible for increment or decrement the days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click events need to be inside of a $(document).ready(function(){  }); in order to work.  Like this...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Next Day Link
    $('a#next').click(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
        refreshSchedule();
        return false;
    });

    // Previous Day Link
    $('a#previous').click(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', '-1');
        refreshSchedule();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```